# Can't Align UI Sprites Correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm trying to create a script for UI elements that can take in a string, a Scriptable Object of chars paired with custom sprites, and create a set of UI objects with Image components that altogether recreate the input string. It's working as expected for the most part, but I'm having trouble getting the objects being created to space out correctly.

Here's what the script to create and place the objects currently looks like. The code creating positioning the objects is all in `SetText()`. Don't worry about the alignment stuff, it shouldn't be having any effect right now, and I'll get to implementing it once this issue is sorted out.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class SpriteTextRenderer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] SpriteFont font;
    Dictionary<char, Sprite> characters;
    [SerializeField] Material material;
    public int pixelOverlap = 0;
    public bool useFontOverlap = true;
    [SerializeField] string currentText;
    public string Text {get {return currentText;} private set {currentText = value;}}
    GameObject[] displayText = new GameObject[0];
    [SerializeField] enum alignment
    {
        TopLeft, TopCenter, TopRight,
        MiddleLeft, Center, MiddleRight,
        BottomLeft, BottomCenter, BottomRight
    }
    const alignment topAlignments = alignment.TopLeft | alignment.TopCenter | alignment.TopRight;
    const alignment middleAlignments = alignment.MiddleLeft | alignment.Center | alignment.MiddleRight;
    const alignment bottomAlignments = alignment.BottomLeft | alignment.BottomCenter | alignment.BottomRight;
    const alignment leftAlignments = alignment.TopLeft | alignment.MiddleLeft | alignment.BottomLeft;
    const alignment centerAlignments = alignment.TopCenter | alignment.Center | alignment.BottomCenter;
    const alignment rightAlignments = alignment.TopRight | alignment.MiddleRight | alignment.BottomRight;

    void Start()
    {
        characters = new Dictionary<char, Sprite>{};
        FillDictionary();
        SetText(currentText);
    }

    void FillDictionary()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < font.characters.Length; i++)
        {
            characters.Add(font.characters[i].character, font.characters[i].sprite);
        }
    }

    public void SetText(string newText)
    {
        GameObject currentCharacter;
        int oldLength = displayText.Length;
        int newLength = newText.Length;
        float characterPosition = 0;
        int overlap = useFontOverlap ? font.pixelOverlap : pixelOverlap;

        if(newLength > oldLength)
        {
            GameObject[] newDisplayText = new GameObject[newLength];
            displayText.CopyTo(newDisplayText, 0);
            displayText = newDisplayText;

            for(int i = oldLength; i < newLength; i++)
            {
                GameObject newCharacter = new("Character (" + newText[i] + ")", typeof(RectTransform), typeof(Image));
                newCharacter.transform.SetParent(this.transform, false);
                newCharacter.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);
                newCharacter.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 1);
                displayText[i] = newCharacter;
            }
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < newLength; i++)
        {
            currentCharacter = displayText[i];

            if(i + 1 > oldLength || currentText[i] != newText[i])
            {
                Sprite newSprite = characters[newText[i]];
                float newSpriteWidth = newSprite.rect.width;
                currentCharacter.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = newSprite;

                RectTransform rt = currentCharacter.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
                rt.localPosition = new Vector2(characterPosition, 0);
                currentCharacter.GetComponent<Image>().SetNativeSize();
                characterPosition += (newSpriteWidth - overlap) * newSprite.pixelsPerUnit;
            }
        }

        Text = newText;
        Debug.Log(currentText);
    }
}
```

And here's what the `SpriteFont` class looks like:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Sprite Font", menuName = "Sprite Font")]
public class SpriteFont : ScriptableObject
{
    public int pixelOverlap;
    public SpriteCharacter[] characters;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class SpriteCharacter
{
    public char character;
    public Sprite sprite;
}
```

The `overlap` value in `SpriteTextRenderer` is meant to denote how much each UI sprite should overlap in texels. Since the "Large Segment" SpriteFont I'm using has its overlap set to one and the UI object running the script has `useFontOverlap` set to true, I'm expecting the text to look something like this (the input string is "1:06.237"):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUirg.png)

However, it comes out looking like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKjFH.png)

Use of `Debug.Log()` has confirmed that `overlap` is being set correctly, and all the sprites in the Sprite Font are sliced perfectly "snug", in that their rects in the Sprite Editor are large enough to cover the visible pixels and nothing more, at least on the x axis. All the sprites' pivots are set to top-left, and the spritesheet has a Pixels per Unit of 19.2.

Comment: what is the parent ? as you dont seem to set a left position it sounds like it is spreading them out for you

Comment: I don't think that's it, the parent object (the transparent white rectangle in the second image) is to the left of where the child objects start (which I plan to fix by adding the alignment options). Also, changing the 'characterPosition += (newSpriteWidth - overlap) * newSprite.pixelsPerUnit;' line near the bottom has resulted in the child objects becoming much closer or farther from each other.